# textToBePresentInElementValue does not work

Tags: protractor

`browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElementValue(this.AddReport, "test"), 30000, "AddReport value is not present timing out");`

here AddReport contains a attribute called value="test", it waits and times out but never finds the element with value="test"

Comment: Just checking that you are not overwriting a global object `element` in the snippet. Also are you ignoring synchronization?

Comment: NO, Element is not global object I have updated the above. I am not ignoring synchronization.

Comment: If your `AddReport` is a form control:  textbox or textarea,  please tell me what words you typed into them?